# Controller cannot find view after removing from Main.js

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am very new to Sencha so this is probably a newbie error :)

I am trying to implement page navigation in Sencha. The following scenario WORKS.

I have a Main.js with a Home screen and a Login screen. When I enter credentials I am forwarded to Home.js.

However, I now want to remove the Home from the Main, because it can only be shown after a login. But, after removing the xtype home from the Main.js, it cannot be found anymore. I don't understand why.

**Main.js**

```
config : {
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom',

    items : [{
        xtype : 'startview',
    }, {
        xtype : 'contactform'
    }, {
        xtype : 'loginform'
    }, {
        xtype : 'createaccountform'
    }, {
        xtype : 'homeview' REMOVING THIS MAKES THE HOME undefined in the controller
    }]
}
```

**My controller**

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.LoginController", {
extend : "Ext.app.Controller",

xtype : 'logincontroller',

requires : ['Ext.app.Router', 'MyApp.view.Home'],

config : {
    refs : {
        loginForm : "#loginFormPanel",
        home : 'homeview'
    },

    routes : {
        login : 'authenticateuser'
    },
    control : {
        'button[action=login]' : {
            tap : "authenticateUser"
        }
    },
    views : ['Login', 'Home']
},

authenticateUser : function(button) {

            **// WHEN REMOVING xtype: homeview from MAIN this getter returns undefined (??)**
    var activeView = this.getHome(); 

    this.getLoginForm().submit({
        url : 'php/process_login.php',
        method : 'POST',
        success : function(form, result) {

            alert('Success and moving to home ' + activeView);
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(activeView);
        },
        failure : function(form, result) {

            alert('2');

            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'failure....' + result);
        }
    });
}
});
```

**Home.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Home', {
extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
id : 'home',
xtype : 'homeview',
requires : ['Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video'],
config : {
    title : 'Home',
    iconCls : 'home',
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom',

    items : [{
        xtype : 'searchview',
    }, {
        xtype : 'profileview'
    }, {
        xtype : 'messagesview'
    }, {
        xtype : 'sensesview'
    }]

}
```

});

**app.js**

```
views : ['Start', 'Main', 'Contact', 'Login', 'CreateAccount', 'Home', 'Messages', 'Profile', 'Search', 'Senses'],

controllers : ['LoginController'],
```

So, how can I make sure I still get a reference to Home in the controller (after removing from main)??

Thanks for your help,
Coen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to give `Home` an `itemId` instead of of an `id`.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Home', {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    itemId : 'home',
    xtype : 'homeview',
    ...
});
```

And now in your controller, You want to reference it like this:

```
...
config : {
refs : {
    loginForm : "#loginFormPanel",
    home : {
            autoCreate: true,
            selector: '#home',
            xtype: 'homeview'
        }
},
...
```

Comment: thanks that was it ! the autocreate part with the selector :)